# Null/duplicate check in a column based on another column filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on pandas with the below requierment

[image]

I need to check the below conditions
if criteria is A, then m shouldn't be null
if criteria is B then n shouldn't be null

I wrote the below code for it

```
df_filter = df.loc[df['criteria']]=='A',[m]] #for A condition check
```

or

```
df_filter = df.query("criteria == A")[m]
```

but both are not giving correct result

I have also tried

```
df_filter = df.loc[(df["criteria"] == "A") & ~ (df["m"].isnull()]
```

but this giving the columns without null..

I need to check if there are any null values exist in m column if A is selected from criteria.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) for test not missing values, if need chain another condition use `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df_filter = df[(df["criteria"].eq("A") & df["m"].notna()) | 
                (df["criteria"].eq("B") & df["n"].notna())]
```

If no values are empty strings:

```
df_filter = df[(df["criteria"].eq("A") & df["m"].ne('')) | 
                (df["criteria"].eq("B") & df["n"].ne(''))]
```